# select options list in taxonomy term filter translated

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

In a multilingual website, I have a view with an exposed filter on a taxonomy term (translated). The filter is exposed as a dropdown menu ().

The multilingual option for the vocabulary is "localize".

When the view is displayed in the main language, the options (=vocabulary terms) are sorted alphabetically.

If the view is displayed in the secondary language, then the options are not properly sorted. 
I discovered that they are sorted again as the main language, but then they are translated and  consequently the order is wrong.

Any idea on how to fix this?